# Facebook SDK : invalide scope : basic info use public_profile, user friends instead

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I'm using facebook sdk 3.15 to set a facebook login button on my project.
keep in mind that I'm working with parse.com

I used the code provided by parse.com support, available [here](https://github.com/ParsePlatform/IntegratingFacebookTutorial/tree/master/IntegratingFacebookTutorial-Android) but I keep getting this error after I click on the login button :

```
invalide scope : basic info use public_profile, user friends instead
```

I googled the error and found nothing...

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using Graph API v2.0, hence the permission `basic_info` is no longer available.

See https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_0_permissions

> `basic_info` is no longer available.

Check what you set as `scope` parameter in the Login URL.

Comment: That was the answer I got from parse support. problem solved. thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem,like the below image:

[image]

Then I change my code from: `self.loginView.readPermissions = @[@"basic_info"];` to `self.loginView.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"user_friends"];` to solved the problem. With the **loginView** is  declaration into the header file:`@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBLoginView *loginView;`