# Can't get email address using facebook sdk for IOS

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook

```
FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
[FBSDKProfile enableUpdatesOnAccessTokenChange:YES];
login.loginBehavior = FBSDKLoginBehaviorSystemAccount;
[login logInWithReadPermissions:@ [@"email"]  handler:^(FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult *result, NSError *error) {
    if (error)
    {
         [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    }
    else if (result.isCancelled)
    {
         [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [MBProgressHUD hideHUDForView:self.view animated:YES];
        if ([result.grantedPermissions containsObject:@"email"])
        {
            if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken])
            {
                [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
                 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
                     if (!error) {
                         NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);
                     }
                 }];
            }
        }
    }
}];
```

I want to get email address for FB user, But from above code I'm just getting id and name only.
Can anyone please suggest me how can I get email address?

Comment: hope this helps you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323244/facebook-ios-sdk-4-0how-to-get-user-email-address-from-fbsdkprofile

Comment: What error do you run into exactly?

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/30275960/4536708 @Amit

Comment: fetched user:{
    id ="";
    name = "";
}
i m only getting id and name not email id

Comment: @DharmeshDhorajiya - Thanks, isuue has been resolved.

Comment: if user does not have added in his profile, then it won't come, as few people are signing up through mobile too. Also make sure permission is given

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to pass perameter whatever u want to read
Like

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:@{@"fields": @"id, name, link, first_name, last_name, picture.type(large), email, birthday, bio ,location ,friends ,hometown , friendlists"}]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error)
         {
             NSLog(@"resultis:%@",result);
         }
         else
         {
             NSLog(@"Error %@",error);
         }
     }];
```