# Unable to access user details userName , imageURL after login using AWS SDK iOS version 2.6.1

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services

I am trying to access the user name and user Image url after login using AWS SDK iOS but i am getting following error :

> Value of type 'AWSIdentityManager' has no member 'identityProfile'
>   Although the same code was working fine in previous SDK(2.5.10),
>   please help me in getting the user details after login.

My current SDK version is 2.6.1

Here is my code :-

```
     if let identityUserName = identityManager.identityProfile?.userName {
          print("User ID\( identityManager.identityId!)")
           print("User name\(identityUserName)")
        }


        if let imageURL = identityManager.identityProfile?.imageURL {
         print(imageURL)               
        }
```

I have managed to access the user Name by using following code if i login with custom login , but if i try to login with Facebook or Gmail i get nil in response.

Code   :-

```
let currUserPool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.default()

let currUser = currUserPool.currentUser()

let username = currUser?.username
```

Answer (score 1):

The Sample Application downloaded from AWS Mobile Hub had the IdentityProfile which helps you retrieve the username and imageURL. On 08/31, the IdentityProfile was removed from the Sample Application and the AWSIdentityManager was moved to an SDK library available as 
`pod 'AWSAuthCore', '~> 2.6'` if you are using cocoapods.

For UserPools:

For retrieving the username from UserPoolsSignIn, you can do the following:

Add this import:

```
import AWSUserPoolsSignIn

AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider.sharedInstance().getUserPool().currentUser()?.username
```

For Facebook:

[How to get user name and email id for Facebook SDK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22010459/how-to-get-user-name-and-email-id-for-facebook-sdk)

For Google:

https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/ios/people